# Collapse table columns as needed (up to min-width) to fit text in first column fully

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with following requirement:

A **fixed-width** HTML table should have several columns. The information in the first column is top priority and should always be visible. The remaining columns should always reduce their width so that text in first column's cells is always visible.

I managed to make a table that maintains fixed width and collapses columns in order to fit:

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
td {
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Very important text, do not collapse!</td>
<!-- These columns should always collapse to fit the important text -->
<td>aaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa</td>
<td>aaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa</td></tr>

</table>
```

This table collapses all columns evenly, which is not what I want. I tried to disable overflow for the first column:

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
td {
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td.no-overflow {
  overflow: initial;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="no-overflow">Very important text, do not collapse!</td>
<!-- These columns should always collapse to fit the important text -->
<td>aaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa</td>
<td>aaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa</td></tr>

</table>
```

Not sure if all browsers show the same, but in Firefox this shows the first column over the remaining ones and out of the table - the text freely flows outside of the element.

I also tried:

- `width: auto;`, `width: fill;` on the first column. That has no effect whatsoever, the columns remain evenly sized.
- `width: -moz-max-content;` works but all other colums dissappear completely. `min-width` is ignored

  ```css
  table {
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    table-layout:fixed;
  }
  td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #EEE;
  }
  td {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width:2em;
  }
  td.no-overflow {
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: -webkit-max-content;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td class="no-overflow">Very important text, do not collapse!</td>
  <!-- These columns should always collapse to fit the important text -->
  <td>aaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa</td>
  <td>aaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa</td></tr>

  </table>
  ```

So to reiterate: Collapse all but the first column in order to fit the first column's text. Do not collapse completely, maintain a `min-width: 2em` for all columns. The table **must** have fixed width, it cannot expand to fit the columns.

I'm out of ideas. I don't want to use javascript for this.

Comment: If the first column width is equal to your table fix width (in this exemple 200px), a x-scrollbar to see the other columns is it a solution for you? If not, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @ReSedano That's the problem, I need the first column to expand, but somehow not over the whole table. It should expand so that the remaining columns can maintain their min-width.

Comment: Ok, but if we put your table in an another div with width:200px or max-width:200px and an overflow-x:scroll, is a solution for you?

Comment: No scroll bars. The idea is that the table will be displayed on phone screen and fills the whole screen. But because phone screens are small, I need to make sure the first column is visible. For now, I solved it by using fixed widths for all columns -  but that's not what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table {
  width: auto;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
td {
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width:60px;
}
td:first-child {
  max-width:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>Very important text, do not collapse!</td>
<!-- These columns should always collapse to fit the important text -->
<td>aaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa</td>
<td>aaaa aaaa aaaa aaa aaa aaa</td></tr>

</table>
```

This work, set the max-width on td instead table then unset the max-width on the important td.

Comment: The table itself needs to have fixed width. It cannot be allowed to expand.